# Constant placement in a ReactJS component

Tags: reactjs

Coming from a Java background, it would seem to me that the constant below should be defined within the class as an instance variable. However, this doesn't work and if I want to access a variable from different functions then the constant has to be defined outside of the component class. Can someone please explain this reasoning to me? Am I just missing something simple?

I got this code from codeacademy.com.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const redPanda = {
  src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Endangered_Red_Panda.jpg',
  alt: 'Red Panda',
  width: '200px',
};

class RedPanda extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Cute Red Panda</h1>
        <img src={redPanda.src} alt={redPanda.alt} width={redPanda.width} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<RedPanda />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: you can use ```export``` and ```import``` for using a variable which has defined outside a component.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you want to define some constant values like style or image URLs then it's always better to define that outside of component. It will become global values and available inside each function/class of that file.

Another option of defining constants is on a class instance itself, but then that variable will be available only inside the class. It means if you defined two classes inside the same file, then one class variable would not be available inside another class.

Like this:

```
class ABC extends React.Component{
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.a = 10;
      this.b = 20;
   }

   render(){
      console.log(this.a, this.b);
      return (....);
   }
}
```

**Note:** React classes don't have the feature of class level properties; we can only define methods. But if you want to define values then you need to use [class transform properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 9):

Create a constants.js for shared constant variables/objects and export it from there for better maintainability.

```js
export const redPanda = {
  src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Endangered_Red_Panda.jpg',
  alt: 'Red Panda',
  width: '200px',
};

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { redPanda } from 'path/to/your/constants/file'; //import from your constants.js

class RedPanda extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Cute Red Panda</h1>
        <img src={redPanda.src} alt={redPanda.alt} width={redPanda.width} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<RedPanda />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like the following:

In another class (for example, `App.js`) use the following code:

```
export const redPanda = {
  src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Endangered_Red_Panda.jpg',
  alt: 'Red Panda',
  width:  '200px'
};
```

In your `RedPanda` component use the following:

`import {redPanda} from './App';`

The best way is to define all of your global constants in a file and name it something like `common.js` or `global.js` and import from it inside other components and files.